# authentication problem (authentication succeed but turn to 'n/A' in another page

Tags: symfony

hello I have a big problem in my authentification process when the user is authenticated it shows this [the authentication result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nJz1.png) and this [the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8ccO.png)  but when I change the route to go to. a page /offres it tell me that it is not authenticated [na](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6iYl.png) I don't where the problem can be I check the code a thousand times but I didn't find any odd things

please any idea where the problem can be ?I had two firewall I deleted the second to see where is the problem y trying just with one here is 
`

```
security:

    encoders :
        App\Entity\Candidat:
            algorithm: auto

        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        in_memory: { memory: ~ }
        in_db_candidat:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\Candidat
                property: email

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        candidat:
            pattern: ^/candidat
            anonymous: lazy
            provider: in_db_candidat
            form_login:
                login_path: app_login
                check_path: app_login
                always_use_default_target_path: true
            logout:
                path: app_logout
                target: offres
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\LoginAuthenticator
                # where to redirect after logout
                # target: app_any_route


    access_control:
```

`
I don't know how to configure it I tries juste with pattern : ^/ it works but if I have two firewalls the sys takes only the first with ^/

Comment: The session handler is certainly not activated.

Comment: I  let  the framework.yaml  by default

Comment: By default, session handler is unactivated.

Comment: ok I'll see the doc for that I'm a beginner I don't know much things about that thinks

Comment: You should enable the session handler as [described in this section](https://symfony.com/doc/current/session.html), then come back to say us if your problem is solved. Set Lines 5 and 8 of framework.yaml like in the doc.

Comment: thinks I didi like you told me and I changed the firewall configuration and it woks thinks

Comment: I have put the answer. Please validate it, to avoid other contributors to read it and to help coders who will encounter the same issue :)

Answer (score 0):

You are well connected, then the response redirect you to another page where you are nomore connected. This is a session problem. By default, session service is unactivated.

You should enable the session handler [as described in this section](https://symfony.com/doc/current/session.html). Set Lines 5 and 8 of framework.yaml like in the doc.

```yaml
# config/packages/framework.yaml
framework:
    session:
        # enables the support of sessions in the app
        enabled: true
        # ID of the service used for session storage.
        # NULL means that Symfony uses PHP default session mechanism
        handler_id: null
```